If the set $A\cap B$ has $4$ elements, prove that $a\in(−2, 0).$
The problem
Consider the sets $A=\{x\in \mathbb{R}\;|\;
x^2+a|x|+b=0\}$ and $B=\{x\in \mathbb{R}\;|\;[x]^2+m[x]+n=0\}$ with $a,b,m,n \in \mathbb{R}, n\geq 0$.
If the set $A\cap B$ has $4$ elements, prove that $a\in(−2, 0).$
(We denote by $[\alpha]$ the integer part of the real number $\alpha$.)
My style
The only thing I observed is that the sets look like some quadratics so I solved them
$|x|=\frac{-a \pm \sqrt{a^2-4b}}{2}, [x]=\frac{-m \pm \sqrt{m^2-4n}}{2}, $
I don't know what else to do from here, because there are a lot of cases to take.

My first try, which might not succeed, would be to assume that $~x = P + r ~: ~P \in \Bbb{Z}, ~0 \leq r < 1.$

For what it's worth, virtually every MathSE posted question that I have seen, that followed this article on MathSE protocol has been upvoted rather than downvoted.  I am not necessarily advocating this protocol.  Instead, I am merely stating a fact: if you scrupulously follow the linked article, skipping/omitting nothing, you virtually guarantee a positive response.

@user2661923 How is it going to help?

$~[x] = P, ~$ and $~|x| = - x \iff x < 0 \iff P < 0.$

Also, $~[x] = x \iff r = 0.$

@IONELABUCIU, what do you mean when you write “the integer part of the real number $a$”? The greatest integer less than or equal to $a$ ? Or do you mean something else?

@IONELABUCIU, perhaps you mean that $A={x\in \mathbb{R};|;
x^2+a|x|+b\color{red}{=0}}$ and $B={x\in \mathbb{R};|;[x]^2+m[x]+n\color{red}{=0}}$ with $a,\color{red}b,m,n \in \mathbb{R}, n\geq 0.;$ Or am I wrong?

@Angelo that's notation for floor function, yeah what you just described should be correct use of notation.

@Angelo You are right, sorry for my mispelling

First, let us consider $A$.
Solving $x^2+a|x|+b=0$ gives $|x|=\alpha,\beta$ where $$\alpha=\frac{-a-\sqrt{a^2-4b}}{2},\ \beta=\frac{-a+\sqrt{a^2-4b}}{2}$$ Since $A$ has to have four elements, we have to have $$a^2-4b\gt 0,\ \alpha\gt 0,\ \beta\gt 0\tag1$$
So, we can write $A=\{\pm\alpha,\pm\beta\}$ where we have $$-\beta\lt -\alpha\lt 0\lt\alpha\lt\beta\tag2$$
$$[-\beta]\le [-\alpha]\lt 0\le [\alpha]\le [\beta]\tag3$$
Next, let us consider $B$.
Suppose that $n\gt 0$. Then, it follows from Vieta's formulas that the product of the two solutions $[x]$ of $[x]^2+m[x]+n=0$ has to be positive. However, it follows from $(3)$ that this is impossible. So, we have to have $n=0$.
Solving $[x]^2+m[x]=0$ gives $[x]=0,-m$.
Suppose that $\beta\ge 1$. Then, since $[\beta]$ cannot be $0$, we have to have $[\beta]=-m(\ge 1)$, and so we have to have $\alpha\lt 1$, i.e. $[\alpha]=0$. However, from $(3)$, $[x]^2+m[x]=0$ has a negative solution. So, this means that $[x]^2+m[x]=0$ has to have three distinct solutions $[x]$, which is impossible.
So, we have to have
$$\beta\lt 1\tag4$$
From $(1)$, we have $a\lt\sqrt{a^2-4b}\lt -a$ which implies $a\lt -a$, i.e. $a\lt 0$.
From $(1)(4)$, we have $0\lt \sqrt{a^2-4b}\lt a+2$ which implies $0\lt a+2$, i.e. $-2\lt a$.$\ \blacksquare$

and how does $[x]^2+m*[x]$ has a negative solution?

thanks so much for your answer, but may I ask why delta cant be 0

The even function $ x^2+a|x|+b$ has four roots. Since these only give rise to two integer parts there is a non-negative integer $l$ such that two of the roots are in $(l,l+1)$ and two in $(-l-1,-l)$.
The two integer parts, $l$ and $-l-1$, are roots of $[x]^2+m[x]+n=0$ and so have product $n\ge0$. Therefore $l=0$.
The two positive roots are then in $(0,1)$. Since their average value is $\frac{-a}{2}$, $a$ is in $(-2,0)$.

can you look at the questions I asked on the other post?
